# how to import a html template in Flask?

Tags: html, css, templates, flask

I am trying to get this html template - https://www.free-css.com/free-css-templates/page231/catalyst

when unzipped, the folder contains -

- the main 'index.html'
- a css folder
- a Font-Awesome folder with fonts
- an image folder

I know I need to put the index.html file in my 'templates' folder, and the css inside of my 'css' folder, but I don't know where to put the font folder or image folder. I have tried a few different things but still end up getting a page with just the html on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put `index.html` in `templates` folder and everything else in `static` folder.

Then, in you `application.py` you can use:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

And in `index.html` file you would link all as path to that resource with ***[url_for](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/#static-files)*** method:

```
<link rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="{{ url_for('static/css', filename='style.css') }}">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static/font-awesome/', filename='font-awesome.min.css') }}">
```

Comment: Thank you! what I was missing was that I needed to change the path of the href's.

Answer (score 0):

Putt the image file into Static Directory. Nevertheless you can also use the static path where the image actually exsist.

File structure:

```
    app.py
static
   |----your_Image.jpg
templates
   |----index.html
```

Then app.py will look like

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/index', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def lionel(): 
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

In templates Index.html will look like

```
<html>
  <head>

  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hi Lionel Messi</h1>

  <img src="{{url_for('static', filename='your_image.jpg')}}" />

  </body>

</html>
```

this way ensures that you are not hard-coding a URL path for your static assets.